# React - Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, methods, unexpected-token

I'm trying to call a method inside `resize()` when the screen width is less than or equal to 900, but I get the error **Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"** how to fix this problem? https://ibb.co/cX0QxS1
https://ibb.co/bQSj1hq

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import less from "./css/lesson.module.css";
import "./css/activeLink.css";
import "./css/betaLesson.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { Navbar } from "../../../Navbar/Navbar";
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';
import * as Icon from 'react-bootstrap-icons';
import styled from "styled-components";
import { slide as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu'

import { NavbarMobile } from '../../../Navbar/Mobile_Navbar/NavbarMobile';

const NextPage = styled.button`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    color: #ff7b77d9;
    padding: 9px 22px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ff7b77d9;
    border-radius: 2px;
`;

export class Lessons extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            indexDescription: 1,
            listActiveIndex: 1,
            sidebarMobile: true,
            menuMobileIsOpen: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize.bind(this));
        this.resize();
    }

    resize() {
        if (window.innerWidth > 900) {
            this.setState({ sidebarMobile: true })
            this.setState({ menuMobileIsOpen: false })
        } else {
            this.setState({ sidebarMobile: false })
        }
    }

    hideMenu() {
        this.setState({ sidebarMobile: false })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", this.resize.bind(this));
    }

    changeDescription(index) {
        this.setState({ indexDescription: index, listActiveIndex: index })
    }

    nextPage() {
        // next page
        this.setState({ indexDescription: this.state.indexDescription + 1, listActiveIndex: this.state.indexDescription + 1 })
    }

    prevPage() {
        // next page
        this.setState({ indexDescription: this.state.indexDescription - 1, listActiveIndex: this.state.indexDescription - 1 })
    }

    showsidebarMobile = () => {
        this.setState({ sidebarMobile: !this.state.sidebarMobile })
    }

    menuMobileIsOpen = () => {
        this.setState({ menuMobileIsOpen: !this.state.menuMobileIsOpen })
    }

    HideMenuMobileIsOpen = () => {
        this.setState({menuMobileIsOpen: false})
    }

    showSettings(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {

        const listLessons = this.props.lesson.map((item, index) => {

            // active link
            const className = this.state.listActiveIndex === index ? 'list_active' : null;

            return (
                <Fragment key={index}>
                    {item.title && (
                        <li className={less.courseTitle}>
                            <div>
                                <p>{item.title}</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    )}

                    {item.titleName && (
                        <li className={className} onClick={this.changeDescription.bind(this, index)}>
                            <div className={less.sidebar_list}>
                                <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon className={less.item_icon} icon={item.iconName} />
                                </div>
                                <div className={less.titleName}>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>{item.titleName}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    )}
                </Fragment>
            );
        });

        return (
            <>
                <div className="abc">
                    <div>
                        <Navbar color="blue" bg="tomato" centerFlexNavbarContainer="flex" LiItem="NavBarli" MainStream="MainStream"
                            navbarSearchPage="Search" navbarHomePage="Home" NavbarMobileIconsBlock="mobile"
                            centerHeadlineNavbarColumn="center" showsidebarMobile={this.showsidebarMobile} menuMobileIsOpen={this.menuMobileIsOpen} />

                        <div>
                            {
                                this.state.menuMobileIsOpen ? <NavbarMobile /> : null
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className={less.wrapper}>
                        <Menu isOpen={this.state.sidebarMobile} >
                            <main id="page-wrap">
                                <div className={less.sidebar}>
                                    <div>
                                        <ul onClick={this.hideMenu.bind(this)}>
                                            {listLessons}
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </main>
                        </Menu>

                        <div>
                            <div className={less.main_content}>
                                <div className={less.main_inside_content}>
                                    <div className={less.header}>
                                        <div className={less.header_next_page}>
                                            <div>
                                                <h2>{this.props.lesson[this.state.indexDescription]["heading"]}</h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className={less.info} onClick={this.HideMenuMobileIsOpen.bind(this)}>
                                        <div className={less.description}>
                                            {
                                                ReactHtmlParser(this.props.lesson[this.state.indexDescription]["data"]["description"])
                                            }
                                            <div className={less.btn_Next_Prev_Container}>
                                                <div>
                                                    {
                                                        this.state.indexDescription >= 2 ?
                                                            <NextPage onClick={this.prevPage.bind(this)} > <Icon.ArrowLeft className={less.arrowLeft} /> Back </NextPage>
                                                            :
                                                            null
                                                    }
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <NextPage onClick={this.nextPage.bind(this)} > Next <Icon.ArrowRight className={less.arrowRight} /> </NextPage>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`hideMenu` is invalid syntax. You're kind of declaring a function in the style of a class method inside of a class method, and also trying to setState inside of the method without actually calling it.

```
    if (window.innerWidth < 900) {
        hideMenu() {
            this.setState({ sidebarMobile: false })
        }
    }
```

You'd need to either...

a) Forgo attempting to call a function and simply set state:

```
    if (window.innerWidth < 900) {
       this.setState({ sidebarMobile: false })
    }
```

b) Declare your function as a class method and call it within your condition, like this:

```
hideMenu() {
  this.setState({ sidebarMobile: false })
}

resize() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 900) {
        this.setState({ sidebarMobile: true })
        this.setState({ menuMobileIsOpen: false })
    } else {
        this.setState({ sidebarMobile: false })
    }

    if (window.innerWidth < 900) {
        this.hideMenu()
    }
}
```

If you're trying to create `hideMenu` inside of your class method, you would do this:

```
resize() {
    const hideMenu = () => this.setState({ sidebarMobile: false })
    
    if (window.innerWidth > 900) {
        this.setState({ sidebarMobile: true })
        this.setState({ menuMobileIsOpen: false })
    } else {
        this.setState({ sidebarMobile: false })
    }

    if (window.innerWidth < 900) {
        hideMenu()
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use the last example, but I get an error that Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: Ohh, yeah, you'll have to either bind hideMenu to `this`, or use an arrow function. I'd use an array function for simplicity's sake. Arrow functions will bind to the parent scope automatically. I'll update the example.

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives the same error, I think it is related to the scope you mentioned https://ibb.co/gtG78SM

Comment: If you're using hideMenu in your markup, it has to be declared as a class method, otherwise you'll run into scope issues. So out of my examples, use example `b`.

Comment: I tried using the example b) but in this case the method works ignoring the check if `(window.innerWidth <900) {this.hideMenu ()}` that is, it works even when the screen is above 900 pixels

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing from your code and your errors, `hideMenu` is triggered in (from what I can tell, I dont have all of your code) scenarios:
1) When the screen resizes.
2) When <ul> is clicked.

It sounds like your original issue has been resolved -- now you're experiencing issues with when the method is fired, which might require a new post since we'd need more information to evaluate what's going on.

Comment: I have updated my question, please can see my whole code

Comment: I see `sidebarMobile` is set to true initially. When you set a breakpoint in the `else` of resize, is it hit when your app initially loads in desktop view (above 900px)? If so, check innerWidth to see what its value is. If that doesn't help, check your Navbar to see if there's a condition that's being evaluated on render to cause `sidebarMobile` to update to `false`.